# How to use Template Literals in Cypress It() command description

Tags: mocha.js, cypress

When I put a template literal in the description of an It command, the template literal does not get evaluated, instead, the template literal code is displayed.

```
let title = "Page Tile";
it('Find Page Title = ${title}' , function () {
    cy.title({ timeout: 90000 }).should('include', title)
});
```

The output looks like: Find Page Title = ${title}

I was hoping for output of: Find Page Title = Page Tile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using backticks. `` instead of ''.